# css inline styles not applying to react table cells when using className

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to apply inline css to the react table cell, shown in the code by *** surrounding the div element. It works as it is declared right now, using Style=.... , but I would like to use className='textvertalign'instead, and when I try using className it doesn't seem to work. I can't seem to put my finger on why it doesn't work with className. It would be nice to be able to reference this css as I plan on applying it to more cells. Thanks in advance.

```
const styles = theme => ({
    textvertalign:{
    display:'flex', justifyContent:'center'
    }
});

class UserManagement extends React.Component {
return
<div>
    <ReactTable key={this.state.tablePageSize} 
        data={this.state.portalUsers} 
        filterable 
        defaultFilterMethod={filterCaseInsensitive}
        columns={[{
             columns: [{
                 Header: <div style={{ fontSize: '16px', textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Edit</div>,
                 width: 90,
                 id: "Edit",
                 className: "align-center",
                 Cell: ({ row }) => (
                     ***<div style={{display:'flex', justifyContent:'center'}}>***
                         <button className="FlatButton"
                             onClick={e => this.handleDialogOpen(e, row)}>
                             {
                                 <FontAwesomeIcon style={{ color: '#FF3933' }} icon="edit" />
                             }
                          </button>
                     </div>
                 )
             }....
    </ReactTable>
</div>
}
UserManagement.propTypes = {
classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,};

export default withStyles(styles)(UserManagement);
```

Comment: what does `withStyles` do? are you sure that adds a css rule?

Comment: Thank you. I used that as the focal point for my searches and figured out how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the explanation and solution here: https://codex.happyfuncorp.com/styling-and-theming-with-material-ui-react-material-design-3ba2d2f0ef25

To be able to use the css that are in styles, I have to add: 
    const {classes} = this.props; //in render
    className={classes.textvertalign} //to reference that css.

I think this has to do with the withStyles exporting the css, and we need to import it back in to use it.